# How to use a subselect in a LEFT JOIN ON clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, exasol

I have a table t with

| ORD_DATE | ORD_ID | ORD_REF | ORD_TYPE1 | ORD_TYPE2 | PRODNUM | PRODQUAL | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-01 | 101 | 101 | ORDER | ORDER | 456 | F | 555 |
| 2020-09-02 | 102 | 101 | CONF | ORDER | 456 | F | 555 |
| 2020-11-30 | 103 | 102 | ORDER | ORDER | 123 | K | 444 |
| 2020-12-01 | 104 | 102 | CONF | ORDER | 123 | K | 444 |
| 2020-12-01 | 105 | 103 | ORDER | ORDER | 123 | K | 444 |
| 2020-12-01 | 106 | 104 | ORDER | ORDER | 123 | K | 333 |
| 2020-12-02 | 107 | 104 | CONF | ORDER | 123 | K | 333 |
| 2020-12-08 | 108 | 104 | CONF | RETURN | 123 | K | -333 |
| 2020-12-01 | 109 | 105 | ORDER | ORDER | 123 | F | 222 |
| 2020-12-02 | 110 | 105 | CONF | ORDER | 123 | F | 222 |

and a table s with:

| ORD_DATE | PROD_NUMBER | PROD_QUAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01-00.00.00.000000 | 123 | K |
| 2020-12-01-00.00.00.000000 | 123 | L |

- In table t are all sales per day.
- A sale has 2 stages: first the order is generated when the customer buys something
  ("ORDER"/"ORDER"). Then it gets confirmed which is at the next day or within the next days normally ("CONF"/"ORDER"). If a customer sends the product back it's a return ("CONF"/"RETURN").

In table s are the products that are "second hand".

- if a product is in that table it means all sales from table t with

> ```
> ORDER_TYPE_1 = "ORDER"
> AND ORDER_TYPE_2 = "ORDER"
> AND t.ORD_DATE >= s.ORD_DATE
> AND t.PROD_NUMBER = s.PROD_NUMBER
> AND t.PROD_QUAL = s.PROD_QUAL
> ```

count as "second hand".

I need the sum of all "second hand" sales that are confirmed from the year 2021 and month 12. But only rows with CONF/ORDER or CONF/RETURN should be in the calculation. I have CAL_YEAR and CAL_MONTH in table t for that (omitted for less clutter).

From table t only ORDER_REF 105 matches that and the sum would be 0 because only these 2 rows matter:

```
| 2020-12-02 | 107    | 104     | CONF      | ORDER     | 123     | K        | 333
| 2020-12-08 | 108    | 104     | CONF      | RETURN    | 123     | K        | -333
```

My code so far:

```
SELECT SUM(PRICE)
FROM t
--
LEFT JOIN s
ON t.PRODNUM = s.PRODNUM
AND t.PRODQUAL = s.PRODQUAL
AND (SELECT ORD_DATE FROM t WHERE ORDER_TYPE_1 = 'ORDER' AND ORDER_TYPE_2 = 'ORDER') >= s.ORD_DATE
--
WHERE CAL_YEAR = 2021
AND CAL_MONTH = 12
AND ORDER_TYPE_1 = 'CONF'
AND ORDER_TYPE_2 IN ('ORDER', 'RETURN')
--
GROUP BY PRICE
;
```

> SQL-Error: "single-row subquery returns more than one row

My problem is limiting the LEFT JOIN to ORDER/ORDER (so that ORDER_REF 105 is in) but only use CONF/ORDER and CONF/RETURN for the sum (so that ORDER_REF 102 is out).

Anyone can help?

Comment: It's not clear that you need the subquery in the join condition... can't you just say `t.order_type_1 = 'ORDER'...`? But I think my bigger question is, why do you want to join to `s` at all if `t` has all the information you need?

Comment: t has no information when a product starts getting sold as "second hand". That information is only in table s.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Thanks for clarifying. (When I read "if a product is in that table it means all sales from table t with" I thought it meant "s is ... all sales from table t with".) It's still not clear to me why you want a subquery in the join condition, though, instead of referencing the `t` you are joining.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the expected output for your sample data.

Comment: Join the subquery instead,

Comment: I couldn't follow all your business rules, but looks like an [`outer apply`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1) might help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of would be to do a self-join, where you join a *second copy of table t* aliased `t2` to use for the CONF/ORDER and CONF/RETURN rows, while you use `t` for the ORDER/ORDER rows.

```
SELECT SUM(t2.PRICE)
FROM t
--
INNER JOIN t t2
ON t2.ORD_REF = t.ORD_REF
AND t2.ORDER_TYPE_1 = 'CONF'
AND t2.ORDER_TYPE_2 IN ('ORDER', 'RETURN')
-- 
LEFT JOIN s
ON t.PRODNUM = s.PRODNUM
AND t.PRODQUAL = s.PRODQUAL
AND t.ORD_DATE >= s.ORD_DATE
--
WHERE t.CAL_YEAR = 2021
AND t.CAL_MONTH = 12
AND t.ORDER_TYPE_1 = 'ORDER'
AND t.ORDER_TYPE_2 = 'ORDER'
;
```

If you need it to be more efficient, you could use analytic/window functions to pull the summed price from the CONF rows into the ORDER/ORDER row as a new column. This way it will only query table `t` once instead of twice.

```
SELECT SUM(t2.order_price_sum)
FROM (select t.*, 
            sum(case when ORDER_TYPE_1 = 'CONF' 
                          AND ORDER_TYPE_2 IN ('ORDER', 'RETURN') 
                     then t.price 
                     else 0 end) over (partition by ord_ref) as order_price_sum
            from t) t2
--
LEFT JOIN s
ON t2.PRODNUM = s.PRODNUM
AND t2.PRODQUAL = s.PRODQUAL
AND t2.ord_date >= s.ORD_DATE
--
WHERE CAL_YEAR = 2021
AND CAL_MONTH = 12
AND ORDER_TYPE_1 = 'ORDER'
AND ORDER_TYPE_2 = 'ORDER'
;
```